# Adding linebreaks within cells in CSV - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

This is essentially the same question asked here: [How can you parse excel CSV data that contains linebreaks in the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278375/how-can-you-parse-excel-csv-data-that-contains-linebreaks-in-the-data)

But I'm using Python 3 to write my CSV file. Does anyone know if there's a way to add line breaks to cell values from Python?

Here's an example of what the CSV should look like:

```
"order_number1", "item1\nitem2"
"order_number2", "item1"
"order_number3", "item1\nitem2\nitem3"
```

I've tried appending HTML line breaks between each item but the system to where I upload the data doesn't seem to recognize HTML.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the code you're using now

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after playing around and I feel so stupid.

```
            for key in dictionary:
                outfile.writerow({
                    "Order ID": key,
                    "Item":  "\n".join(dictionary[key])
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here's an example of what the CSV should look like:
>
> ```
> "order_number1", "item1\nitem2"
> "order_number2", "item1"
> "order_number3", "item1\nitem2\nitem3"
> ```

The proper way to use newlines in fields is like this:

```
"order_number1","item1
item2"
"order_number2","item1"
"order_number3","item1
item2
item3"
```

The `\n` you show are just part of the string. Some software may convert it to a newline, other software may not.

Also try to avoid spaces around the separators.