# PHP CSV Importer : Multiple rows due to line break in one column

Tags: php, csv, import

Trying to import data from CSV files using PHP Codeigniter.
The file has column `description` in which the data entered has some enter or new line within a cell but it does not create a new row in CSV. On the other hand, while importing using php it generates a new row in the loop which is being inserted as a new record in the database.

How to resolve this issue. Picture attached.

```
$csv_array = $this->csvreader->parse_file($file_path); 

   foreach ($csv_array as $row) {  
           $description =$row['description'];
           echo '<pre>';
           var_dump(($row));
            
}
```

[image: THE CSV FILE]

Comment: Try reverse engineering by looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278375/how-can-you-parse-excel-csv-data-that-contains-linebreaks-in-the-data

Comment: Sounds like `$this->csvreader->parse_file` is not reading the data correctly in the first place. Probably needs some additional settings for field delimiters, escape characters, or something like that. But you neglected to tell us, what that actually is - a method of some framework, something you have written yourself, …?

Comment: @CBroe Hi, Yes written my self but actually this is in Codeigniter. The linebreaks in csv file are creating problems, otherwise the `$this->csvreader->parse_file` is working fine.

Comment: If you are not using `fgetcsv` in there to read the actual lines from the CSV file, then you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @CBroe I am using codeigniter csvreader

Comment: Then check if you have it configured correctly regarding delimiters & escape characters.